# match any key from couchdb design

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchdb

I am new to couchdb,I have a design with two key. I am using node to view the list. Is there anyway I can pass only one key from node and if it matches any of the two key from couchdb and fetch me result.

**My design in couchdb:**

```
function(doc) {
if(doc.doc_type==="messages")
  emit([doc.from, doc.to], doc);
}
```

**Passing key using node**

```
db.view('message','fetch_msg',{key:"user1"}, function(err, body) {      
    if(err)console.log(JSON.stringify(err))
        console.log(body.rows.length)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(body));
})
```

Like 'user1' is one of the key.
message/fetch_msg is my design.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can emit multiple keys per doc - every key will return the same doc.

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.doc_type !== 'messages')
    return

  emit(doc.from, null)
  emit(doc.to, null)
}
```

If you want to fetch the whole doc of a row it's recommended for performance reasons to not emit it as value of the row. Use `?include_docs=true` instead when you request the view.

Comment: yeah actually i already tried this function(doc) {
if(doc.doc_type==="messages")
  emit(doc.from, doc);
if(doc.doc_type==="messages")
  emit(doc.to, doc);
}

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like [this](http://ryankirkman.com/2011/03/30/advanced-filtering-with-couchdb-views.html).
You can specify the other parameter as `{}` in the key. So that the key becomes `["user1", {}]` or `[{}, "user1"]`. You can use the start key, endkey concept of couchdb for your case.